# Is there a way to assign an internal string or identifier or tag to a matplotlib artist?

Tags: matplotlib

Sometimes it is useful to assign a 'tag', which can be a simple string, to a `matplotlib` artist in order to later find it easily.

If we imagine a scenario where say `plt.Line2D` had a property called `tag` which can be retrieved using `plt.Line2D.get_tag()` it would be very easy to find it later in a complicated plot.

The only thing I can find that looks remotely similar is the group ID: for example `line.set_gid()` and `line.get_gid()`. I haven't found any good documentation on this. The only reference is [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_gid.html). Is this meant for such use as described above? Is it reserved for other operations in `matplotlib`?

This would be very useful for grouping different artists and then performing operations on them later, for example:

```
for line in ax.get_lines():
    if line.get_tag() == 'group A'
        line.set_color('red')
        # or whatever other operation
```

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `gid` for such purposes. The only side-effect is that those names will appear in a saved svg file as the gid tag.

Alternatively you can assign any attribute to a python object.

```
line, = plt.plot(...)
line.myid = "group A"
```

just make sure not to use any existing attribute in such case.

Comment: Perhaps the latter option is cleaner then. What is the original purpose of ```gid``` then?

Comment: SVG has a group ID (gid) specification. This parameter is used to set the gid if given. There is no harm in using it.